# Bootstrap 4 - change navbar-brand font

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble accessing the text inside my navbar-brand in a bootstrap 4 page I am working on.

Here is part of my html code for a navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand">Houston Chamber Music Network</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
                </li>
```

I have left off much of this code because right now I'm focused on the navbar-brand.

I have a linked css document but I have been unable to access the text within the navbar-brand in order to change color and other attributes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

u have to put tag(p or h1, etc...) and give class to your navbar-brand text.

```
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <h5 class="bg-info">Houston Chamber Music Network</h5>
            </a>
```